# I want to Display all the strings in my queue

Tags: c++

This is my code  , I want to display all I put on tail and Head in this c++ program. I want the program display all the queue elements when I click displayAll(). I edited the code, by adding the full details of the code. Not idea to show all elements in the queue , I able to see the size of the queue but not the elements with they string like a table. I do not know if that is possible.

```
class Node {
public:
    string name;
    string gender;
    string birthDate;
    string SSN;

    Node* next;
    Node(string name, string gender,string birthDate,string SSN) {
        this->name = name;
        this->gender = gender;
        this->birthDate = birthDate;
        this->SSN = SSN;
        next = NULL;
    }
};

class Queue {
private:
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    int size;
public:
    Queue() {
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
        size = 0;
    }

    int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    bool isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

    void addPatient() {
        string name;
        string gender;
        string birthDate;
        string SSN;
        Node* next;
        cout << "Enter Patient name: ";
        cin >> name;
        cout << "Enter patient gender: ";
        cin >> gender;
        cout << "Enter patient birth date: ";
        cin >> birthDate;
        cout << "Enter patient SSN: ";
        cin >> SSN;


        Node* n = new Node(name, gender, birthDate, SSN);
        
        if (head == NULL) {
            head = n;
            tail = n;
        }
        else {
            tail->next = n;
            tail = n;
        }
        
        size++;
    
    }


    void showFront() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        cout << "Name: "+ head->name << "\n" << "Gender: "+ head->gender << "\n" << "Birth Date: " + head->birthDate << " \n" <<"SSN: "+ head->SSN << "\n";
    }

    void showLast() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        cout << "Name: " + tail->name << "\n" << "Gender: " + tail->gender << "\n" << "Birth Date: " + tail->birthDate << " \n" << "SSN: " + tail->SSN << "\n";
    }


    void displayAllPatients() {
        cout << "Patients are: " << "\n";
        

    }
```

Comment: Thing with a queue is you're supposed to only be able to look at one end and insert to the other. Usually you have to empty the queue to print it, but nothing says you can't remember the first item you remove and insert it back in again. Keep removing and reinserting and when you find that first item again, you're done. Mind you this only works if there are no duplicates, so you might have to do something smarter.

Comment: I commited the full code for review

Comment: Can't you have a simple while loop traversing each node from head to tail?

Comment: If you have the head, you just need to traverse items till the end (tail).

Comment: Since you control the queue n this case, why not add a function to `Queue` that prints the contents of the queue, and then call that?

Comment: As previously mentioned, you may want to read on queue traversal. Starting from `head` you can display the data of all the nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple loop like this will do:

```
void displayAllPatients() {
    cout << "Patients are: " << "\n";
    auto p = head;
    while(p) {
        cout << p->name <<  "\n";
        p = p->next;
    }
}
```

or

```
    for(auto p = head; p; p = p->next) {
        cout << p->name <<  "\n";
    }
```

Comment: This give me a infinite loop

Comment: @VanchyTechMer Do you have a circular reference in your queue? Like some item's `next` pointing to itself? Or to `head`?

Comment: @VladFeinstein the code shown in the OP's question is a null-terminated linked list, not a circular list.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, I understand that that was an intent. I was guessing as what might be wrong. I doubt that my loops, as written, may go into an infinite loop on a correct null-terminated list.